# List to Text or Replace word in Text File

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, text, replace

So I have a text file that contains:

Toy_One Ordered
Toy_Two Ordered
Toy_Three Ordered

I want to remove the " Ordered" from the text file.  I figured making a list and rewriting to the file would be simple, or even a replace but clearly not.  So far, I have been only able to rewrite Toy_Three.

```
Infile = (src.txt, "r")
g = list(Infile)
stripg = [mark.strip() for mark in g]

for line in stripg:
    entry = line.split(" Ordered")
    NewList = list(entry[0])

    InOutFile = (src, "w")
    for final in NewList:
        InOutFile.write(final)
```

My outcome is just Toy_Three

I've also tried "pickle" but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it:

```
Infile = (src.txt, "r")
magic = Infile.readlines()

delete = [" Ordered"]
Outfile = (src.txt, "w")
for line in magic:
    for word in delte:
        line = line.replace(word,"")
    Outfile.write(line)
```